# Repeat same numbers after particular number

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a logic like user gives a date. I compare with current date and calculate the difference. According the difference, I send back them a message. I have set of 4 messages. If the difference is 1 then I send 1st message from set of 4. My confusion is, If the difference is 5 then it should send 1st message, if difference is 6 then it should send 2nd message. Because I have only 4 messages. Basically I'm trying to create a method where I give 5 as parameter and I give back 1 as result. Give 6 and get 2 and it goes on.

**Code**

```
var userDate;
var todayDate = new Date();
var diff = moment.duration(moment(userDate).diff(moment(todayDate)));
if(diff > 4){
   diff = 1;
}
```

This logic didn't worked out for me. Please help me out.

Comment: You probably want the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest option is the remainder operator:

```typescript
function getDiff(num) {
  return num % 5
}
```

Or the same but more verbose:

```typescript
function getDiff(num) {
  return num - (Math.floor(num/5) * 5)
}
```